# Difference between discrete PFET and NFET + PFET load switch circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, switches

I'm confused at what the benefit of having a PFET controlled by an NFET is when just a PFET can be used for load switch applications. In this context, Vin would be around 50 V so a Zener diode would need to be tied between Vin and the gate. I've read that active low outputs aren't desired for controlling switches, but in this context, even if active high is applied to drive the gate, the Vgs would still be well above the threshold voltage and turn the PFET on. Also wondering why MOSFETs are preferred in these applications over BJTs. Would really appreciate if someone could help me out here. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you wouldn't be able to turn the PFET off anymore without the NFET.

Your microcontroller has 5V outputs at best. That means that the output controlling the PFET can either be 0V or 5V. Since the PFET's source terminal is at 50V, you'll either give it 50V source-gate voltage (50V - 0V), or 45V (50V - 5V). In either case, the PFET would be on. You won't be able to turn it off.

The NFET acts as a level shifter (voltage level translator). It turns the 0V/5V signal from the microcontroller into a 0V/50V signal for the PFET, enabling you to actually turn it off.

You still have to limit the PFET's gate voltage with a zener diode and series resistor, of course, unless your PFET can tolerate 50V on its gate.

MOSFETs are preferred due to their lower conduction losses and zero gate current. That doesn't mean that there aren't applications where a BJT is better, though.

Comment: to add to this answer using the NFET also gives you another advantage, you do not have to worry about isolating the gate circuit in this case, since you can afford to connect the source of the NFET to ground. If you made a gate signal directly to the PFET Vout can be floating so you would have to figure out a solution for the gate circuit to also be floating

Comment: Couldn't a Zener diode with say a 45V rating be tied from the source to the gate of the PMOS? Then a 5 V input at the gate would be present which can be controlled and within the MOSFET requirements, right?

Comment: @krishna A 45V zener from gate to source would just limit the gate-source voltage to 45V. Then you'd have 45V no matter what the microcontroller is doing. You really need a voltage level translator.